# Center Justify/align ASCII art in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, terminal, ascii-art

I was just working on my bash project and

> I want the header ascii art to automatically adjust at the center whenever the terminal executes the script in whatever resolution. Is it possible mates?
>   Following is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo
echo -e "\t\t1▄██████▄#0000▄████████0000▄████████11▄██████▄ ";
echo -e "\t\t███0000███111███0110███111███1011███1███#0000██";
echo -e "\t\t███0001███111███0111███111███1100█▀11███#ffff██";
echo -e "\t\t███0010███11▄███▄▄▄▄██▀11▄███▄▄▄11111███#0000██";
echo -e "\t\t███0011███1▀▀███▀▀▀▀▀111▀▀███▀▀▀11111███#ffff██";
echo -e "\t\t███0100███1▀███████████111███1101█▄11███#0000██";
echo -e "\t\t███0101███111███1000███111███1110███1███#ffff██";
echo -e "\t\t1▀██████▀ffff███1001███111██████████11▀██████▀1";
echo -e "\n\n"
```

Comment: If you have lines of varying width, the you can use a variation, e.g. `printf "%$(( ( ${COLUMNS} - ${#string}) / 2 ))s\n" "$string"` (for equal widths, a fixed indent shown by choroba is the way to to)

Comment: Once again, David.
You are the real homie,

Comment: You are going to be the ANSI/ASCII Art expert when you are done with this project `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the COLUMNS environment variable that returns the width of the terminal.

```
banner_width=46
indent=$(( (COLUMNS - banner_width) / 2 ))
prefix=''
for ((i=1; i<=indent; i++)) ; do
    prefix+=' '
done
echo
echo -e "${prefix}1▄██████▄#0000▄████████0000▄████████11▄██████▄ ";
```

Comment: In case it is not an interactive shell, I recommend to insert the following at the beginning, because otherwise variable COLUMNS is not set: `COLUMNS=$(tput cols)` or `eval $(resize)`